# C# web.config List of services

Tags: c#, web-config, sorting

I want to store a list of services (servers and service names) in a web.config file.
There could be any number and I need to be able to sort them in stop/start order.

Of course I can do this in any number of ways, but this is the kind of thing I need to do time and time again and I'm looking for the most elegant solutions.

So what are the most elegant solutions for
(a) storing a number of multi-attribute elements (serviceName, serverName, order) in web.config, and
(b) sorting them into their specified order

Thanks for all suggestions :)

Comment: not understand, why do you not save the data in a List? web.config file is not a place for you to store data

Comment: Well, it is actually config data. The application is a control panel for windows services. At the moment there are only 2. I don't want to use a database because the database could be one of the services!

Comment: @Eric Yin, its pretty obvious what the user is trying to achieve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Custom [ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/2tw134k3.aspx), this allows you to define your own Configuration Secion, Elements and Sorting on the collection, how to manage duplicate entries etc.

Something alone these lines:

```
<section name="myServices" type="MyNameSpace.MyCustomConfigurationSectionHandler, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />

// I've placed order into the setting in case it is to be persisted or predefined
<myServices>    
  <add serviceName="MyFirstService" serverName="MyService" order="0" />
</myServices>
```

Comment: I like that a lot and I never knew you could do it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Keep then in xml file and use linq to xml to query, sort them to your needs

Comment: The OP specified the web.config file.

Comment: @Lloyd offering another perspective doesn't hurt. It is not that complicated to change from web.config to xml

Answer (score -1):

Normally in a .config you just have key/value pairs in your appSettings. However if you have more than two items you can choose a delimiter to split additional items in the value string. Each item is just based on position and you can have as many comma delimited values as you want. You can use any value for the key and you can always sort within the LINQ.

```
       <appSettings>
          <add key="order" value="servername, ipaddress, anothervalue"/>
       </appSettings>

       var cfg = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

        var servers =
            from key in cfg.AllKeys
            select new {
                order = key,
                servername = cfg[key].Split(',')[0],
                ipaddress = cfg[key].Split(',')[1],
                anothervalue = cfg[key].Split(',')[2]
            };
```

Comment: "Normally in a .config you just have key/value pairs in your appSettings" this is incorrect, .config files are for configuration settings, AppSettings are a section within the overall configuration file.

Comment: Yes, what I am saying is that appSettings traditionally consist of one key and one value mapped to that key; however as a solution to this question you could split the single value into multiple values with a delimiter. I'm not saying that appSettings is the only content in a .config.

Comment: Its not really a solution, what would happen if any of the values contained the deliminater, which is highly likely given the values the OP defined.